# Raspberry Pi 2 LCD display not working

Tags: raspberry-pi2, lcd

I have raspberry Pi 2, ready-built ADS1118 development board, thermocouple
I have code that will record temperature reading. The problem I have is LCD display of the ADS1118 is not working. It will work with raspberryPI B+, 
but not the raspberry PI 2.

I have done some research, but found out raspberry pi 2 now by default uses Device Tree.The main impact of using Device Tree is to change from everything on, relying on module blacklisting to manage contention, to everything off unless requested by the DTB.

I have gone to the config.txt and added the following changes:

```
    dtparam=i2c_arm=on
    dtparam=i2s=on
    dtparam=spi=on

    # Uncomment one of these lines to enable an audio interface
    dtoverlay=hifiberry-amp
    dtoverlay=hifiberry-dac
    dtoverlay=hifiberry-dacplus
    dtoverlay=hifiberry-digi
    dtoverlay=iqaudio-dac
    dtoverlay=iqaudio-dacplus

    # Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
    dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

    # Uncomment this to override the defaults for the lirc-rpi module
    dtparam=gpio_out_pin=16
    dtparam=gpio_in_pin=17
    dtparam=gpio_in_pull=down
```

It is still not working!

Link to Project I'm Following
https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberrypi_projects/blog/2014/11/14/temperature-measurement-for-lab-and-science-projects?et=blogs.comment.created#comment-79089

I believe the code is fine because it work perfectly fine on raspberry pi 1, but LCD display on ADS1118 development board wont work when I use a Raspberry PI 2.

I am looking for suggestions. I believe it is a setting on Raspberry PI 2 that is disabling LCD display

Comment: Dunno if you've posted yet, but you will probably get more interest on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, will do that